# Entity framework - Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, formatexception

I've been having error for a while now, and while reading all the other posts her on SO, I didn't get much more cleaver.

When making a database call I get the error:

```
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero
```

I have the following method which gives me the error:

```
    public bool IsUserInRole(User user, string roleName)
    {
        using (var repository = new SaxoPublishingEntities())
        {
            repository.Attach(user);

            // THIS CALLS GIVE ME THE ERRROR
            var roles = repository.UserRoles.Include("Users").Where(userRole =>
                userRole.Name == roleName && userRole.Users.Contains(user)).ToList();


            if (roles.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My database model:

[image]

My stack trace:

```
[FormatException: Indekset (nulbaseret) skal være større end eller lig med nul og mindre end størrelsen af argumentlisten.]
   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +10610374
   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +63
   System.Data.EntityRes.GetString(String name, Object[] args) +363
   System.Data.Entity.Strings.ELinq_UnsupportedConstant(Object p0) +95
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq) +1256
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression) +136
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +1011
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq) +122
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input) +168
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding) +161
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda) +168
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) +66
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) +47
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +169
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression linq) +53
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) +197
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) +47
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +169
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert() +50
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +593
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +255
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +89
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +100
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +31
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +56
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +97
   System.Linq.Queryable.Any(IQueryable`1 source) +233
   Saxo.Publishing.Business.UserServiceOLD.IsUserInRole(User user, String roleName) in c:\Users\laho\Documents\GitHub\SaxoPublishing\Development\Saxo Publishing\Saxo.Publishing.Business\UserServiceOLD.cs:175
   Saxo.Publishing.Web.Security.UserPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) in c:\Users\laho\Documents\GitHub\SaxoPublishing\Development\Saxo Publishing\Saxo.Publishing.Web\Security\User\UserPrincipal.cs:42
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +421
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +143
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +978
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +538
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +531
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +447
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +388
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Any ideas is HIGHLY appreciated! :-)

**Attempted rewrite version 1:**

```
public bool IsUserInRole(User user, string roleName)
    {
        using (var repository = new SaxoPublishingEntities())
        {

            var users = repository.Users.Where(c => c.Id == user.Id);

            if (users.Any())
            {
                var myUser = users.First();
                var roles = repository.UserRoles.Where(userRole =>
                    userRole.Name == roleName && userRole.Users.Contains(myUser)).ToList();

                if (roles.Any())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try searching for a `UserID` instead of attaching the `User` and using `userRole.Users.Contains(user)`

Comment: @DStanley Thanks, just tried - saw error. You can see my attempted code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a cryptic message for a well-known EF restriction: you can't use reference types in `Contains`. In stead do this:

```
var userId = user.Id;
var roles = repository.UserRoles.Where(userRole => userRole.Name == roleName
                  && userRole.Users.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(userId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `user.Id` is not a negative number,
and also all the column `Id` for all rows in the two database tables `User` and `UserRole` are never below zero?

Comment: We are using guids, and yes, that is handled.. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

The method you posted is not the source of your error. Look at the exception - you have a call to `AppendFormat` somewhere on a `StringBuilder`, and the format string you are using has a replace token (i.e. `{0}`) that does not have a corresponding replacement variable.

EDIT: check out the trace:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +10610374
System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +63
System.Data.EntityRes.GetString(String name, Object[] args) +363
System.Data.Entity.Strings.ELinq_UnsupportedConstant(Object p0) +95
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq) +1256
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +162
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression) +136
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +1011
```

This looks like the error is originating in the Linq-To-Entity code provider you're using; You are pulling some sort of "conversion string" in `EntityRes.GetString` - my guess is that format string has an error in it. Given the rest of the stack trace, I would *guess* that somewhere in your LINQ query you are referring to a constant it doesn't know how to map properly - possibly in a contains clause?

Other things to check in the method you posted:

- `user` is not null
- `userRole` is not null
- `myUser` appears 'valid'
- `userRole.Name` is not empty/whitespace/null

Comment: Yeah, probably right.. But I can't see how that's the case? When I step through we code I get the error on that line, and that line talks to the automated database first scheme from entity framework. Any ideas?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard If I had to guess, I'd say you've got some resource string somewhere that is the wrong format - I'll edit my answer with my limited analysis.